# Twitter API rate limit to the number of retweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I am trying to extract the screen names of twitter users who have retweeted a particular tweet. This is the code that I have in Python

```
# Connect to Twitter
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print (api.rate_limit_status())

# Get original Tweet details
status = api.get_status(839200990293180416)
retweets = api.retweets (status.id)
print ("Tweet %s, originally posted by %s, was retweeted by..." %(status.id, status.user.screen_name))

# Getting all the retweets
for retweet in retweets:
    print (retweet.user.screen_name)
    unconnected[retweet.user.screen_name] = retweet.user;
```

For this particular tweet (https://twitter.com/yumisakugawa/status/839200990293180416), I know that there are 42 retweets, but I am only getting the results for 18 retweets. The same thing seems to happen with other tweets where there are more than >18-20 retweets.

Is this due to the retweet API rate limitation? I thought that the limit was 100 retweets. Can someone help me with this?